# Contract address collision

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

So from my understanding when creating a contract the two variables that are used in determining what the address of the contract will be are the msg.sender and the nonce value. So if I create two contracts in the same transaction such as I did with this code https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0xcb7d7e99e56406a675173f0ddbde7d8cc3392e5e#code

Why did it generate two contracts at two different addresses, what I though would happen is that they would generate at the same address and the one would simply overwrite the other or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're understanding of the contract address determined by the address of the message creator and the nonce is correct. However, in the example you posted, `msg.sender` is the address of the `Test` contract.

These are the steps that occured:

1. You initiated the transaction to deploy `Test` from your external account  (`0x98081ce968e5643c15de9c024de96b18be8e5ace`). According to the transaction information, the nonce of the account at that time was 639.
2. This resulted in the `Test` contract having an address of `0xcb7d7e99e56406a675173f0ddbde7d8cc3392e5e`.
3. During the deployment of `Test`, the constructor then creates two new contracts through "internal transactions". `Divert` is deployed from the contract address at `0xcb7d7e99e56406a675173f0ddbde7d8cc3392e5e` with `nonce=1`. `OverRide` is deployed from the same address with `nonce=2`.

You can view the details of the internal transaction [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x1a9ef6baf09878897572ce68b8625482b54c2d1bffc829f4ccb64b21b02844e3#internal).

Comment: So even if I wanted to there is no way to override a contract and have two created at the same address?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. It would be a bad thing if you could. You can submit two transactions from one address with the same nonce, but one of them is guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Just FYI, these days contract nonces start at 1.

Comment: @smarx...Yep. I updated the answer. I actually thought of that while I was typing and STILL put the wrong values in.